# k means cross validation

Tags: k-means, cross-validation

I have been given a list of USA counties which contains data such as poverty, population etc and performed a clustering with a k means algorithm. I cross-validated the clustering as follows: I split the counties to a training set and a holdout set. I left the poverty feature out during the clustering and then for each county in the holdout set I found the nearest cluster and then I subtracted the county's poverty from the average poverty of the nearest cluster. Finally I squared the difference above, summed for every county in the holdout set and then divided by the number of counties in the holdout set. Then I did the same but this time the poverty feature took part in the clustering. I observed that the error was significantly lower than before but I read that this is somehow 'cheating'. What is an intuitive way to understand why include the poverty in clustering is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to determine the poverty attribute by using the poverty attribute.

As another example, assume you have a set of cars. You know that some features of a car strengthens the likelihood of it having a certain color. You don't know the color of the cars (except for the training set) but you know a lot of other attributes, like model and year. You build a clustering model using the training set and then applies it to the main set. The clusters should now contain cars of the same colors.

You didn't know the colors beforehand but you were (hopefully) able to use the other attributes to cluster the cars according to color anyway.

If you used the color attribute to build your clustering model you would achieve nothing. You would use the color to cluster similar-colored cars. Impressive. What knowledge would you gain?

Comment: That was exactly the kind of answer I was looking for!